# Partition a list into groups by specifying group ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, partition

I have a list, say:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

and I want to create another list with group IDs, for example, if I split `my_list` into 2 groups, the group IDs list would be:

```
group_id = [1,1,1,2,2,2,2]
```

where the last group contains 1 more element due to the fact that `my_list` contains a prime number of elements.

Here are all possible splits, from 7 groups to 1 group:

```
group_id = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]  # 7 groups, 7 elements
group_id = [1,1,2,3,4,5,6]  # 6 groups, 7 elements
group_id = [1,1,2,2,3,4,5]  # 5 groups, 7 elements
group_id = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4]  # 4 groups, 7 elements
group_id = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3]  # 3 groups, 7 elements
group_id = [1,1,1,2,2,2,2]  # 2 groups, 7 elements
group_id = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]  # 1 group, 7 elements.
```

The problem is I don't know how to enforce this condition that the groups need to be more or less equal in size. This has to work for whatever list length (not only 7) and provide me `group_id` lists of a given number of groups (from 1 to `len(my_list)`).

EDIT:

This seems to "somewhat" work, though not fully:

```
import math

my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
n_groups = 3


k = math.ceil(len(my_list)/n_groups)
chunks = [my_list[x:x+k] for x in range(0, len(my_list), k)]
group_id_nested = [[chunks.index(i)+1]*len(i) for i in chunks]
group_id = [item for sublist in group_id_nested for item in sublist]
```

Comment: Start by clearly defining what ' more or less equal' would mean.

Comment: Is `group_id` always sorted?

Comment: @Ch3steR I does not have to be sorted.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille "more or less" would mean there is a threshold (say 2) by which one cgroup cannot be larger than the other.

Comment: `group_id = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3]` why wouldn't this be split into 2 groups of 2 and one group of 3 (`[1,1,1,2,2,3,3]`)?

Comment: @Qubix You should make that really clear in your question.

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 that is an alternative I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are allowed to use `numpy` you might harness [numpy.linspace](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace) for that task following way:

```
import numpy as np
list_size = 7
for n in range(1,list_size+1):
    group_ids = list(map(int,map(round,np.linspace(1,n,num=list_size))))
    print(group_ids)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Idea is simple: I get evenly spaced (float) numbers (`list_size` of them) from `1` (inclusive) to `n` (inclusive) and then get *nearest* integer for each (note usage of `round`). As you can see in each line of output difference between any two group sizes (number of occurence of given number) is always equal to or less 2.

Answer (score 0):

Without numpy:

```
import math
listy = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
groupnum = 6

smallnum = math.floor(len(listy)/groupnum)
bignum = math.ceil(len(listy)/groupnum)

grouped = []
for c,e in enumerate(range(1,groupnum+1)):
    if c<(len(listy)/groupnum - smallnum)*groupnum:
        grouped+=[e]*bignum
    else:
        grouped+=[e]*smallnum
grouped=grouped[0:len(listy)]
print(grouped)
```

Also, it distributes them evenly. For example, it would do `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]` instead of `[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]` to divide into 4 groups.